# Facebook navigate into subpage of page tab app via Browser Url?

Tags: facebook, url, iframe, tabs

is it possible to access a subpage of a page tab app in Facebook via the browser URL? I've programed a lottery game where the users can share/like/send each single post to their wall/friends. The Like-Urls of the Posts link to the plain web-page out of Facebook (e.g. http://my-own-app.com/post/the-post-slug/). But I want to target the URLs to the page tab app directly so that the Facebook will passthrough the data to the app (loaded by iframe) e.g. http ://www.facebook.com/pages/My-Page-Where-the-app-is-included/123456789?sk=app_my-app&**passthrough-url**=http... 
<- is sth. like this possible???

Thanks in advance,
greetings
mbx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in the [Page Tab App Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/) near the bottom - see the section marked 'Integrating with Facebook APIs'

Short version: whatever you pass in the `app_data` parameter as a GET parameter will be passed to your app in the `signed_request` (in a parameter also called `app_data`) sent to your app.